# Code Warrior Assembly code

Tags: codewarrior

I need some advice with a small program for school. If  you could just point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it. I am using CodeWarrior coding in assembly language for the TWR-S12G128 Processor Module. My goal is to get the LEDs turn on and off with a delay of 1 second. Here is what my code looks like:

```
                LDS     #$4000  ; Initializing SP
                LDAA    #$FF     
                STAA    DDRA    ; Defines Port A as output
Back            LDAA    #$FF     
                STAA    PORTA   ; Turning all LEDs ON
                JSR     Delay    
                LDAA    #$00     
                STAA    PORTA   ; Turning all LEDs OFF
                JSR     Delay    
                BSR     Back     
Delay           PSHX            ; 2-clock cycle
                PSHY            ; 2
                LDY     #20     ; 2-clock cycle
LOOP1           LDX     #$FFFF  ; 2
LOOP2           DEX             ; 1-clock cycle
                NOP             ; 1-clock cycle
                BNE     LOOP2   ; 3-clock cycles/last cycle is 1
                DEY             ; 1
                BNE     $FF     ; 3-clock cycles/last cycle is 1
                PULY    LOOP1   ; 3-clock cycle
                PULX            ; 3-clock cycle
                RTS             ; 5-clock cycle
```

There error that I am getting is :

```
Error   : A2400: End of Line expected

main.asm line 58   
Project: Project_4.mcp, Target: Standard, Source File: main.asm

Error   : Compile failed
Project: Project_4.mcp, Target: Standard, Source File: main.asm
```

Comment: And which line is line 58?

Comment: PULY  LOOP1 ; 3-clock cycle

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a great deal about the Freescale architecture but it's very unusual for any architecture to combine a pull instruction with a label.

The `bne $ff` is also unusual since that *does* normally specify a label.

I would be thinking that those two instructions should be more along the lines of:

```
bne loop1
puly
```

That makes more sense in that the pull instruction loses the label and the nested loops are properly constructed.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. I have already tried that and it does compile with no errors but it doesn't do anything to my LEDs.

Comment: @Bertswoot, that would be a _different_ problem, one more to do with the way you're manipulating ports, or the delays involved. It's better asked as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

The $FF on the BNE line is not proper.  I think it's a typo.  I just worked this out with my professor a few hours ago.  Here is the code that will give you the 1 second delay and continuously cycle the 4 LEDs on and off:

```
ABSENTRY Entry                 ; Application entry point
RAMStart    EQU  $2000
ROMStart    EQU  $C000  

    ORG RAMStart
; Insert here your data definition.

PTT         EQU   $240
DDRT        EQU   $242

; code section
            ORG   ROMStart
Entry:
_Startup:
           LDS    #$4000
Back       LDAA   #$FF
           STAA   DDRT
           LDAA   #$FF
           STAA   PTT
           JSR    Delay
           LDAA   #$00
           STAA   PTT 
           JSR    Delay
           BSR    Back

Delay        PSHX       ; 2-clock cycle
             PSHY       ; 2
             LDY    #20 ; 2-clock cycle
LOOP1        LDX    #$FFFF  ; 2
LOOP2        DEX        ; 1-clock cycle
             NOP        ; 1-clock cycle
             BNE    LOOP2   ; 3-clock cycles/last cycle is 1
             DEY        ; 1

           BNE    LOOP1 ; 3-clock cycles/last cycle is 1
           PULY     ; 3-clock cycle
           PULX     ; 3-clock cycle
           RTS      ; 5-clock cycle

           ORG   $FFFE
            DC.W  Entry           ; Reset Vector
```

If someone would be so kind as to help me with the math.  I get the 65,535 * 20 for the loops, but with the 6.25MHz clock, I end up getting .209 secs as the final amount for the delay, but I know it's suppose to be 1 sec. What am I not seeing?

Comment: If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).